# Can one compute 'double' (or even triple) simultaneous derivatives: $\frac{F(x+dx,y+dy)-F(x,y)}{dxdy}$

Tags: derivatives

I have encountered a situation where I need to find the result of the following construction:

$$
\lim_{dx\to 0,dy\to 0} \frac{F(x+dx,y+dy)-F(x,y)}{dxdy}
$$

Is this a valid derivative construction? What is the result of such a thing?

---

In fact, my actual situation has 4 terms:

$$
\lim_{dx\to 0,dy\to 0, dz\to 0, dt\to 0} \frac{F(t+dt, x+dx,y+dy z+dz)-F(t,x,y,z)}{dtdxdydz}
$$

I assume the 2d cases generalizes easily to the 4d case.

Comment: Why not use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative ?

Comment: @zkutch I don't have a choice; this construction is what I get.

Comment: Similar general construction is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative , but your   denominator makes me doubt.

Comment: Suppose that $F: U \to V$ is a function of real vector spaces and $n \in \mathbb N_0$ let $h: \{1,\ldots, n\} \to U$ and $\tau: \{1,\ldots, n\} \to \mathbb R^*$ and $p \in U$. Then a good candidate for the difference quotient for the $n^\text{th}$ derivative of $F$ at point $p$ in the directions given by $h$ would be $\frac{1}{\prod_{i = 1}^n \tau_i} \sum_{X \subseteq \{1,\ldots, n\}} (-1)^{n - |X|}F(p + \sum_{x \in X}\tau_xh_x)$. The limit needed to be taken to get the required derivative is the one where all component $\tau_i$ converge uniformly to $0$ for all  $ i \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$.

Comment: Are you sure that instead of $dxdy$ it should  be $\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}$ ?

Comment: @jimjim ohhh maybe! I'll have to look into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to be divergent for any differentiable function. For instance look at $$F(x,y) = x+y$$
Then
$$\frac{F(x+h,y+k) -F(x,y)}{hk} = \frac{h+k}{hk} = \frac1h +\frac1k$$
Which clearly does not converge as $(h,k) \to 0$

In general if $F$ has continous partial derivatives
$$\frac{F(x+h,y+k) -F(x,y)}{hk}$$
$$=\frac{F(x+h,y+k) -F(x+h,y)+F(x+h,y)-F(x,y)}{hk}$$
$$=\frac1k\frac{F(x+h,y+k) -F(x+h,y)}{h}+\frac1h\frac{F(x+h,y)-F(x,y)}{k}$$
$$=\frac1kD_2F(x+h,\zeta)+\frac1hD_1F(\xi,y)$$
where  $\zeta \in (y,y+k)$ and $\xi \in (x,x+h)$.
This obviously has no limit as $(h,k) \to 0$